# Spark cassendra yugabyte connector issue to fetch records from table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, yugabytedb

**For example below is my code :**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkCassandraApp')\
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'xx.xx.xx.xx') \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', '9042') \
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username","username")\
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password","password")\
    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").option("table","local").option( "keyspace","system").load().select('host_id')
df.show()
```

Getting below errors:

> ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
> java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "host_id"
> FROM "system"."local" WHERE token("key") < ?   ALLOW FILTERING:
> org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$    at
> com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:323)

I'm using

Spark version : **2.4.6**

Scala version : **2.11.12**

spark-cassendra- connecter **spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.5-yb-2.jar**

Answer (score 2):

For Spark 2.4.x you need to use Spark Cassandra Connector 2.4.3 or, better, [freshly released 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all). Spark Cassandra Connector is compatible only with Spark 2.0-2.2. See the [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility).

See [instructions](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/15_python.md) on how to use SCC 2.5.0 with pyspark.

Comment: Thanks Alex for replay, I have tried both of the way but it didn't work

Comment: ScalaReflectionLock is first sign of driver incompatibility... have you done clean after changing package version?